# How to insert Cell in UICollectionVIew Programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and it works fine, but I want to add a few `UICollectionViewCells` items programmatically into the collection view.

So how can I achieve this?

To further clarify: when I say programmatically I mean inserting a cell during runtime, when an action is fired, not when the app is loaded (using the `viewDidLoad` method). I know when the model is updated and the call is made to `UICollectionView` in the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` method. It should create a new cells, but it's not doing that, it's throwing an error.

Comment: When you say "it's throwing an error" it's *very* helpful to say what that error is in your question. It's normally useful to see the actual code too, not just some text vaguely describing it.

Comment: Ok ill post the code shortly. thanks Flexo

Answer (score 26, accepted):

...By referring to [UICollectionView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)

> You can accomplish:
>
> Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Sections and Items To insert, delete,
>   or move a single section or item, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Update the data in your data source object.
> 2. Call the appropriate method of the collection view to insert or delete the section or item.
>
> It is critical that you update your data source before notifying the
>   collection view of any changes. The collection view methods assume
>   that your data source contains the currently correct data. If it does
>   not, the collection view might receive the wrong set of items from
>   your data source or ask for items that are not there and crash your
>   app. When you add, delete, or move a single item programmatically, the
>   collection view’s methods automatically create animations to reflect
>   the changes. If you want to animate multiple changes together, though,
>   you must perform all insert, delete, or move calls inside a block and
>   pass that block to the performBatchUpdates:completion: method. The
>   batch update process then animates all of your changes at the same
>   time and you can freely mix calls to insert, delete, or move items
>   within the same block.

From your Question: you can for example register A gesture Recognizer, and Insert  a NEW cell by 
doing the following:

in

```
// in .h 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *data;

// in .m 
@synthesize data
// 

- (void)ViewDidLoad{
      //.... 

    myCollectonView.dataSource = self;
    myCollectionView.delegate = self; 
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"1", @"2" @"3", @"4", 
                                                   @"5",@"6", @"7",  @"8", @"9",  
                                                   @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13",
                                                   @"14", @"15", nil];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = 
     [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addNewCell:)];
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
    //.. 
} 


-(void)addNewCell:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)downGesture {
    NSArray *newData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"otherData", nil];
    [self.myCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        int resultsSize = [self.data count]; //data is the previous array of data
        [self.data addObjectsFromArray:newData];
        NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (int i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + newData.count; i++) {
            [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                              inSection:0]];
        }
        [self.myCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];
    } completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are inserting multiple `items` into `UICollectionView`, you can use `performBatchUpdates:`

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    // Insert the cut/copy items into data source as well as collection view
    for (id item in self.selectedItems) {
        // update your data source array
        [self.images insertObject:item atIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:
          [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];          
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: For inserting an item into collection view you need to specify an indexPath. Here iam performing insertion after cut/copy using menu operations so i know where to insert item. You can create one  indexPath using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]` and then insert item at that indexPath or it could be the selected item indexPath to insert in to the position of the selected item

Comment: [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                
                
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                
                
            }];

       Error may be because you didn't include the completion block

Answer (score 5):

`– insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` does the job

Comment: more examples would be more helpful~~

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to insert an item in Swift 3 :

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:index, section: 0) //at some index
    self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
```

You must first update your data.

Comment: For a collectionView you should really be using `let indexPath = IndexPath(item:index, section: 0)`