# How can I insert a cell at the first position in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

In Objective-C, how can I insert a cell at the first position in UICollectionView? I have a collection of images and I wanted to add a camera button as the first item

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert Cell in UICollectionVIew Programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572462/how-to-insert-cell-in-uicollectionview-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can add the cell in first position in collection view by this:

```
 [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        NSDate *newDate=[NSDate date];
        [datesArray insertObject:newDate atIndex:0];
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];
    } completion:nil];
```